# Need to transfer multiple large files with strong tolerance to delay and intermittency

Tags: linux, ftp, file-transfer, scp

I need to transfer a directory of large files (~1.5G each) from my laptop at locations with variable intermittent connectivity and high round-trip delay (e.g. From hotels in Asia to servers in Virginia).  Since the source is a laptop, it needs to be able to automatically resume infinitely until the file transfers are completed.

As a secondary preference, it would be desirable for multi-session support (even more so if it auto-scale sessions based on reliability).

Anyone know of such a client/server app?

Comment: Please expand your answer with infos such as Operating System, what you have already tried, what you have considered. You have googled for this, right? We don't do product recommendations here, by the way, see [http://superuser.com/help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3):

Use `rsync`.

```
rsync -av --partial dir_with_big_files/ remotehost:~/destdir/
```

The `--partial` option will cause `rsync` to resume interrupted transfers where they left off. You can also include `--progress` if you would like a transfer status indicator.

Answer (score 1):

Another commercial option is Biscom secure file transfer.  Checkpoint restart is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with large file transfers with [BitTorrent Sync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html).  I havent used the Linux version, but the Windows version works well.  It is designed to transfer large files and supports block level changes and resuming transfers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to consider commercial options, [Aspera](http://asperasoft.com/) and [Signiant](http://www.signiant.com/) are leading products for this sort of thing. They'll also be much faster than Rsync or anything SSH-based.

Comment: Can anyone speak to the security of Signiant?  The [privacy policy](https://www.signiant.com/website-privacy/) is not very inspiring.